# highlight multiple words in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I can highlight one word in string like this:

```
$str = "my bird is funny";
     $keyword = "fun";
     $str = preg_replace("/($keyword)/i","<b>$0</b>",$str);
```

Ant this will give me:
my bird is **fun**ny

But how to make this work when keyword is from more than one word for example when

```
$keyword = "bird fun";
```

I would like to get this result: my **bird** is **fun**nny

Comment: Use `explode` with a space on `$keyword`, and create a pattern array to pass to `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the most basic concepts of regular expressions is alternation. `bird|fun` will match either `bird` or `fun`. This alternation can easily be generated using `implode` and `explode`:

```
$keywords = explode(' ', trim($keyword));
$str = preg_replace('/'.implode('|', $keywords).'/i', '<b>$0</b>', $str);
```

As pritaeas pointed out, you could also use `str_replace`:

```
$str = preg_replace('/'.str_replace(' ', '|', trim($keywords)).'/i', '<b>$0</b>', $str);
```

Of course, if you write `$keyword` yourself and don't use it anywhere else then write it as a regex right away:

```
$keyword = 'bird|fun';
```

or even

```
$keyword = '/bird|fun/i';
```

This way you don't need any explode or implode at all.

Comment: As a side note: If OP has control over string `$keyword` it will be better if (s)he replaces spaces with `|`. So (s)he can avoid `explode` and `implode`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$str = "my bird is funny";
$keyword = "bird fun";
$keyword = implode('|',explode(' ',preg_quote($keyword)));
$str = preg_replace("/($keyword)/i","<b>$0</b>",$str);
```

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/uwjZe5)

Comment: I was going to mention preg_quote to others, Nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?
$str = "my bird is funny";
     $keyword= array("bird","fun");
     foreach($keyword as $k=>$v)
{
     $str = preg_replace("/($v)/i","<b>$0</b>",$str);
}
//echo $str;
?>
```